# How to find out the account(s) under which the sql server is running?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, dmv

I have just created a proxy and I need to grant access to the proxy to the account that runs the sql server agent. It will probably be a domain account.

How can I find it using T-SQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 there was no documented way. So undocumented command `xp_regread` was used to get the result

```
DECLARE @sn NVARCHAR(128);

EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SQLSERVERAGENT',
    'ObjectName', 
    @sn OUTPUT;

SELECT @sn;
```

Since SQL Server 2008R2 SP1 we have a documented way to get to this information:  `sys.dm_server_services` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204542.aspx)

You can use below query to find the same:

```
SELECT  DSS.servicename,
        DSS.startup_type_desc,
        DSS.status_desc,
        DSS.last_startup_time,
        DSS.service_account,
        DSS.is_clustered,
        DSS.cluster_nodename,
        DSS.filename,
        DSS.startup_type,
        DSS.status,
        DSS.process_id
FROM    sys.dm_server_services AS DSS;
```

Comment: the first one is a ctrl C + Ctrl V from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7324827/1387418. Please the link.